# List Cons-Into Function?

Tags: erlang

I am often wanting to take one list and cons every element into an existing list.

```
MyList = [3,2,1],
MyNewElements = [4,5,6],
MyNewList = lists:foldl(fun(A, B) -> [A | B] end, MyList, MyNewElements).
%% [6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

Assuming `MyList` has 1M elements and `MyNewElements` only has a few, I want to do this efficiently.

I couldn't figure out which of these functions- if any- did what I was trying to do:
https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html

Comment: How does `MyNewList = lists:reverse(MyNewElements) ++ MyList` perform in comparison?

Comment: @choroba The order doesn't actually matter so much. I assumed the operation `A ++ B` would be `O(A + B)` but that may be a bad assumption. Is it `O(A)`?

Comment: I have no idea, but you can benchmark to see which one is faster.

Comment: Why you should keep a 1M elements list? it's too big. It is the trouble coms from. Could you look the problem from a higher position, and optimize it as a whole? For example, Save data into other place for one limit.

Comment: @ChenYu You are seeing the trees for the forest. It is an example to avoid getting an `O(A+B)` solution when I want an `O(A)` solution.

Comment: You can read the module 'lists.erl" source code, it will give you new idea.

Comment: `A ++ B` is indeed `O(A)`, not `O(A + B)` (see [the efficiency guide](https://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/myths.html#myth--operator--++--is-always-bad))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a short list to the beginning of a long list is cheap - the execution time of the `++` operator is proportional to the length of the first list.  The first list is copied, and the second list is added as the tail without modification.

So in your example, that would be:

```
lists:reverse(MyNewElements) ++ MyList
```

(The execution time of `lists:reverse/1` is also proportional to the length of the argument.)

Comment: I think [`lists:reverse/2`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#reverse-2) should be more efficient, since it must only loop on `MyNewElements` once: `lists:reverse(MyNewElements, MyList)`,

Answer (score 3):

Another option, aside from those already provided, would be just to have

```erlang
NewDeepList = [MyList | DeepList]
```

and modify the reading/traversing to be able to handle `[[element()]]` instead of `[element()]`.

Comment: Definitely an option

Answer (score -1):

Because erlang is function language and is different from c, javascript, it copy variable and modify it, not just modify it. Therefore it is impossible compression to o(A).length(A) is length of new added elements.

Comment: I don't know if i'm following but as a functional language it is actually possible if you use a linked list and only add to the *left* side. i.e. `MyList = [1,2,3], MyNewList = [0|MyList].` Adding `0` to the existing list was an O(1) op.